# Am trying to run a cloned react-native project but i get error in my terminal

Tags: react-native

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')
LOG  Running "farmsell" with {"rootTag":1}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "farmsell" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

i was expecting the app to appear well on my simulator

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the terminal is opened in the correct folder. If not, run `cd folderName` to go inside the correct folder, or `cd ..` to go one level up.

If you are in the correct folder, run `npm i` and then `npm start` and then open a second terminal (leave the first terminal running in the background) and run `npm run Android`. Wait a few minutes and you should be all set.